# Why do I get an error when using Random in Java?

Tags: java, random, integer

I'm trying to change what image I have, depending on the value of a random integer, however, eclipse says that the rand integer needs a body.

I've already tried doing

```
int rand = random.nextInt(4);
```

but that also doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class GrassTile extends Tile {
    Random random = new Random();
    static BufferedImage texture;
    int rand;

    rand = random.nextInt(4);

    if (rand == 0) {
        texture = Assets.grass0;
    } else if(rand == 1) {
        texture = Assets.grass1;
    } else if(rand == 2) {
        texture = Assets.grass2;
    } else if(rand == 3) {
        texture = Assets.grass3;
    }

    public GrassTile(int id) {
        super(texture, id);
    }
}
```

Thanks,
   JavaDev

Comment: You need to put your code inside a method.

Comment: in what context are you trying to change the image?

Comment: like do you want to change the button on click? or by clicking on a button? or does it just appear the first time you start the program?

Comment: because as @Eran you either need to have that code within a method or even your constructor, depending on what you are trying to do

Comment: Basic syntax problems - vote to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not logic
you want to  initialize a texture wich is a static field with a non static field

remove the static keyword for the texture and put the initialization in the constructor

Comment: Thanks, that's fixed my problem, but I'm now getting a new one. If I don't have the super() first, it gives me an error: **"Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor."** Sorry if I sound noobish, I'm still trying to learn.

Comment: yes you must call the super() before any statement, this mean you cannot initialize your texture object before initializing your super class. Maybe this class has a setter for the texture field, wich you can call after the initialization ?